# How to pick two random numbers with no carry when adding

Tags: random

I'm trying to make this algorithm which inputs a lower and upper limit for two numbers (the two numbers may have different lower and upper limits) and outputs two random numbers within that range

The catch is however that when the two numbers are added, no "carry" should be there. This means the sum of the digits in each place should be no more than 9.

How can I make sure that the numbers are truly random and that no carrying occurs when adding the two numbers

Thanks a lot!

Edit: The ranges can vary, the widest range can be 0 to 999. Also, I'm using VBA (Excel)

Comment: What language are you using?  How many digits wide can your random number be?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, all excellent questions. OP, your function will not be "truly random" if it is forced to drop results because of "carrying". Regardless, though, I would advise you to use two functions. One function that just generates random numbers, and another function that modifies the digits of two numbers if the two digits in the same place (on a base-10 system) add to be more than 9.

Comment: @SpencerDoak. I thought on it and was wondering won't some of the combination of numbers be more probable then? ..and I didn't quite understand the second function. How should I modify the digits?

Comment: @SpencerDoak Of course the function will still be random.  It will just have a different distribution than the unconstrained version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy and distributionally correct way of doing this is to use [Rejection Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling), a.k.a. "Acceptance/Rejection".  Generate the values independently, and if the carry constraint is violated repeat.  In pseudocode

```
do {
   generate x, y
} while (x + y > threshold)
```

The number of times the loop will iterate has a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with an expected value of (proportion of sums below the threshold)<sup>-1</sup>.  For example, if you're below the threshold 90% of the time then the long term number of iterations will average out to 10/9, 1.11... iterations per pair generated.  For lower likelihoods of acceptance, it will take more attempts on average.